# Elasticsearch: Adding a filter range to each bucket in a date histogram

Tags: date, elasticsearch, aggregation

In my index I have documents where each document is timestamped (via 'datetime' field) in the format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

I have a query that provides buckets of daily (date histogram) average values for a given field within the document, this works well, no issues.

I'm trying to extend this to filter each bucket so that the daily average only considers timestamps within a certain part of each day (e.g. only documents created in the morning or afternoon etc).

I've tried the following query:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "rating": {
         "date_histogram": {
            "field": "datetime",
            "interval": "1d",
            "time_zone": "Europe/London",
            "min_doc_count": 1
         },
         "aggs": {
            "afternoon": {
               "filter": {
                  "range": {
                     "datetime": {
                        "gte": "12:00:00",
                        "lte": "17:00:00",
                        "format": "HH:mm:ss"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "service": {
                     "avg": {
                        "field": "qr2"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "datetime": {
                  "gte": "2016-08-28T23:00:00",
                  "lte": "2016-09-29T07:34:49"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But this returns null values for the aggregation (0 doc count) even though the parent buckets have multiple documents with timestamps that fall into the time range - see example below:

```
"aggregations": {
      "rating": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key_as_string": "1472428800000",
               "key": 1472425200000,
               "doc_count": 843,
               "afternoon": {
                  "doc_count": 0,
                  "service": {
                     "value": null
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string": "1472515200000",
               "key": 1472511600000,
               "doc_count": 748,
               "afternoon": {
                  "doc_count": 0,
                  "service": {
                     "value": null
                  }
               }
            },
```

I'm guessing that just specifying the time part of the datetime is not having the desired effect, it's probably doing the range query with the date part defaulted to some value, hence not matching any timestamps for docs returned in the parent bucket.

Is there a simple way I can do this or do I need to split time out into a separate field?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer works perfectly. But for versions before 2.1.0, this seems to work

```
{
    "script": {
        "script": "def hod = doc.datetime.date.getHourOfDay(); return hod >= min && hod <= max",
        "params": {
            "min": 12,
            "max": 17
        }
    }
}
```

This is due to an issue the older versions and has been fixed. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1931

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways around this.

The first solution is to index another field called `hourOfTheDay` so that you can run a simple numeric `range` filter on it.

```
           "filter": {
              "range": {
                 "hourOfTheDay": {
                    "gte": 12,
                    "lte": 17
                 }
              }
           },
```

The second solution simply involves using Groovy scripting in a `script` filter

```
           "filter": {
              "script": {
                 "script": {
                    "inline": "def hod = doc.datetime.date.getHourOfDay(); return hod >= min && hod <= max",
                    "params": {
                       "min": 12,
                       "max": 17
                    }
                 }
              }
           },
```

For this second solution, make sure you [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll need to add a time field as we don't want to enable dynamic scripting.